# Переклад "feedback loop"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Чи є усталений переклад терміну "feedback loop"? "Feedback" - це "зворотний зв'язок", "loop" - "петля". Чи можна подавати як "петля зворотного зв'язку"? Чи варто залишити "фідбек"? Чи може краще не "петля", а "коло"?

[Отут](https://nv.ua/ukr/opinion/primer-ministram-50042456.html) навіть побачила такий варіант: "positive loop feedback, або по-простому — маховик, який крутиться сам у потрібному напрямку".

Answer (score 1):

[Словник математики та інформатики 2010 (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко)](https://e2u.org.ua/dicts/meinarovych) подає три способи перекладу для **[feedback](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=feedback&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) loop**

> коло/петля/контур зворотного зв'язку

Цікаво, що [словник-довідник інженерії довкілля 2000 (Тимотей Балабан)](https://e2u.org.ua/dicts/dovkillya) містить таке

> **climate** *(і)* клімат; *(пк)* кліматичний
> **c. feedback loop** кліматична зворотна петля [цикл, контур] *(замкнута система кліматичного зворотного зв’язку)*

Тобто іноді слово *зв'язок* можна пропустити. От ще один схожий приклад звідти ж

> **ice-albedo feedback loop** цикл льодового зворотного відбиття сонячної енергії

Виходить, що тут багато чого залежить від оточення.

[Словник з радіоелектроніки 2015 – 2018 (Богдан Рицар, Леонід Сніцарук, Роман Мисак)](https://e2u.org.ua/dicts/radioelektronika)  додає ще один варіант

> **виток зворотного зв'язку** feedback loop